# Is there any way to send a notification or a text depending upon server query?

Tags: android, database, server, notifications, smtp

I have a local server (configured using XAMPP) that consists primarily of a database which has a few columns (for details), one of which consists of a numerical value.

I want to create something such that once this numerical value column is divisible by 2, a notification is sent to an Android phone that is connected; and if it isn't divisible by 2, another notification is sent. I would like to know if this is possible if my android device is not connected to the system acting as a server as well.

If this isn't possible, in place of this notification, it would be okay if a mail is sent too.

Comment: Instead of using XAMPP make use of Firebase to handle the server side havoc.

Comment: It isn't for a lot of data, but is only meant to be a quick hack; so I figured XAMPP would do the trick.

Comment: Xampp will handle all your data locally but if you want user to handle your data at runtime amd dynamically, then u will need to use fcm

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send push notifications to android without registering with FCM(earlier GCM). Whenever you want to send the notification from your XAMPP sever you need to call the FCM api to send the notification to the android device. for that you need to get the Cloud messaging setup ready as well.

Follow the instructions here [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)